# Relationship between page table size and page size in operating system

Tags: operating-system

How page table size is related to page size in **multi level paging** of logical address space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the basic requirement for multilevel paging is pagetable size less than equal to frame size, and since frame size equals page size, so page table size less than equal to  page size.

Comment: Yeah, i got what you referred by saying page size equals to frame size, knew the fact that the entire page table has to fit inside a frame in main memory. So in a way it has to fit inside inside page size since page size equals frame size. Is this what you meant ?